# Nginx and Dedicated Varnish

Tags: varnish

I’m new in varnish, is it possible configure varnish on dedicated varnish server? I have separate nginx  lb in front of kubernetes cluster. My goal is caching a lot  of static files like .js .css and images  or even static page, so every request cache related to services in  kubernetes cluster will serve in varnish server, is it possible to do that? I attach varnish  configuration, please check

```
10.10.10.27: nginx-lb-01, 10.10.10.28: nginx-lb-02, 10.10.10.29: Varnish
```

I already try to configure but I think it failed because when Im check using varnishstat, there’s no  traffic average statistic. In every nginx  vhost I already  config default port site 8080 & redirect to 443
How can I solve this ?

Thank you
[varnish config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwQ27.png)

Comment: Please include your Nginx vhost, your systemd service configuration for Varnish, and your full VCL file. Please also describe the desired topology. There's Nginx, there's Kubernetes & there's Varnish. I'd like to see this information to figure out which systems connects to what and if there are any content routing rules you have in place.